# Is there any function in Networkx that directly generates adjacency list from a table of nodes

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, networkx

Suppose that an Undirected graph neighboring nodes are given in a txt file as below

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 5
2 6
3 4
```

can I generate an adjacency matrix by a single function in networkx as  below

```
[0 1 1 1 1 0 ]
[1 0 0 0 1 0 ]
[1 0 0 1 0 0 ]   
[1 0 1 0 0 0 ]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 ]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 ]
```

Comment: Should be 1 on 6th row and 6th column? It is not in list...

Comment: @user2014111 you can accept the answer if you think if fit your needs... in case yes, you also get +2 reputation...

Answer (score 4):

It is not really one function, but you can read edges from file and then create adjacency matrix like this:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.read_edgelist('list.txt')
A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
```

which gives

```
matrix([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: How to read edge list for directed graphs can you help me with it

Comment: @user2014111 Have you read the documentation for [`nx.read_edgelist`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html)? `G = nx.read_edgelist('list.txt', create_using=nx.DiGraph())`